# Controlling access to data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I keep running into cases were I want to limit access to data rather than methods.

As an example, I have a users table.  An individual user's record should be visible only to themselves, the helpdesk, and the user's manager.  However, only the manager can edit the user.

I can restricted view and edit methods by the above roles using the authorization attributes, but then I still need to check and see if the current user has the ability to touch the data he is requesting.  This is where the authorization attribute falls short.

I'm currently considering adding an "IsAuthorized" method to all of my models to check and see check if the current user is allowed to perform the current action, but this seems tedious in general, so I wanted to see if anyone else had a centralized way of doing this.

Thanks again!!

(Currently coding everything in ASP.NET C# MVC 4.5.)

Comment: From a data perspective, all you would need to do is restrict it, by passing the current user's ID to any query retrieving it...

Comment: @BrianMains I'm not really sure I understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: If you don't want users to view certain data because of their permissions, don't return that data from the controller; filter it out at the database level.  It's probably going to be hard to talk fundamentals without seeing some code.